# BGE: Add object actuator spawning bullet on wrong angle

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I'm trying to make a turret in blender game engine,

[image: Laser]

(the small red object is the laser)

As you can probably tell, this is a laser turret(top right), but the lasers (nothing special, just a red cube reshaped) are pointing the wrong direction.

I can't really say much more other than give a screenshot of my logic bricks.
[image: Logic bricks]

What fires this object is a empty. And it's called to fire it by the turret you see it's self. No need to show the logic bricks for what calls it, unless needed.

I truly apologize for any mistakes. I tried to look this up, and found no results, and it's 1:47 AM and i need to wake up early tomorrow.

A link to download the .blend: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4psdrb2zf8xcs7x/Cube%20assault%20%3B%29.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the rotation of the laser. go to the laser, rotate it 90* on the z axis, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>>*apply rotation*. this should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you, you answered my question, although it was 90* on the z then the x as well for it too work. :)

Comment: okay, hard to tellfrom just the screenshot

Comment: There is a download the .blend but anyway, thanks. :P

Comment: okay, sorry, i don't really have time to go through them all. :P

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the emitter and all of it's parents have a scale of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0).

If not you might want to apply the current scale to mesh <kbd>Ctrl + A</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: I've got all the scales set to 1.0, 1.0 1.0, already. :/

Comment: The only other option would that the emitting object is rotated at the moment of adding the object. Maybe you post a demo file showing the problem.

Comment: Vincent Scalia answered the question, thanks for the help anyway. :P